# Linux enscript multiple text files to a single PostScript file

Tags: linux, pdf, postscript, enscript

I'm using this code to create a text file from our application, convert it to PostScript using enscript and then convert it to PDF.

```
function print_order
{

  ORDERFORM="Sales Order"
  PARAMFILE="$1.par"

  echo "OUTPUT_TO:FILE:$1.tmp" > $PARAMFILE
  echo "DOCUMENT:$1" >> $PARAMFILE
  echo "FORM_NAME:$ORDERFORM" >> $PARAMFILE

  win_print_order /par:$PARAMFILE

  enscript $1.tmp -p $1.ps
  ps2pdf $1.ps

}
```

In it's current state it works by running `print_order 900100`, this would create a 900100.pdf in the current directory.

But I am looking to be able to save multiple order prints in the same .pdf. Is it possible to pass multiple text files to enscript to create a single PostScript file of all order prints and from there a PDF?

For e.g. `enscript $1.tmp,$2.tmp,$3.tmp -p $1.ps`. Is this possible somehow?

Comment: I know nothing about `enscript`. You should be able to `cat "$@" > $$.tmp` and then run `enscript $$.tmp -p $$.ps`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `enscript` accepts multiple input files and outputs a single file. Try

> `enscript -p $1.ps $1.tmp $2.tmp $3.tmp`

`enscript` accepts many options. See its [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/enscript).

Comment: However it doesn't respect columns parameter and doesn't split in 3 parts, if I ask it to. You will have to print 3 pages